# Installing Ubuntu and get the error cp: write error: No space left on device

Tags: grub2

I downloaded Ubuntu 14.04 x64 Desktop burned it to my 16gb Sand disk USB drive. I rebooted my PC with this in and it came up with the grub 2 loader. I tried running install Ubuntu as well as try Ubuntu but neither worked I finally got them working by adding 'nomodeset=0' which gave me the load screen with the purple background and the logo with five loading dots. Nothing happened for a while so i pressed ESC and it came up with 'cp: write error: no space left on device'. I don't know what to do.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you include the output of: `df -h` by running it in terminal and updating your question. It sounds like you have a partition that needs to be increased in size.